# How to convert vtkImageData to cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, vtk

This question was answered already here:
[Copy vtkImageData to cv::Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891341/copy-vtkimagedata-to-cvmat)

But the link to the answer is not working anymore. So how can I convert from `vtkImageData` to `cv::Mat`?

Comment: ***But the link to the answer is not working anymore*** What happened when you tried? I expect that you had a compiler error because of the API change of vtk. Your question would be better if you try this and add the code and errors to your question as text (no pictures please).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this function here to convert from `vtkImageData` to `cv::Mat`:

```
cv::Mat convertVtkImageDataToCVMat(const vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> &vtkImage) {
  int imageDimensions[3] = {0, 0, 0}; // Width, Hight, Depth --> Depth is not equal to number of image channels!
  vtkImage->GetDimensions(imageDimensions);
  int imageWidth = imageDimensions[0];
  int imageHeight = imageDimensions[1];
  int numberOfImageChannels = vtkImage->GetNumberOfScalarComponents();
  int cvType = 0;
  switch(numberOfImageChannels){
    case 1: cvType = CV_8UC1; break;
    case 3: cvType = CV_8UC3; break;
    case 4: cvType = CV_8UC4; break;
    default: std::cerr << "Check number of vtk image channels!" << std::endl;
  }
  auto resultingCVMat = cv::Mat(imageHeight, imageWidth, cvType);
  // Loop over the vtkImageData contents.
  for ( int heightPos = 0; heightPos < imageHeight; heightPos++ ){
    for ( int widthPos = 0; widthPos < imageWidth; widthPos++ ){
      auto pixel = static_cast<unsigned char *>(vtkImage->GetScalarPointer(widthPos, heightPos, 0));
      resultingCVMat.at<unsigned char>(heightPos, widthPos) = *pixel;
    }
  }
  return resultingCVMat;
}
```

Comment: This results in a strangely scaled image with most of the color information missing